# Override one part of multiple-property css declaration

Tags: css

If I have the declaration:

```
h1 {
  background-image: url(a.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, black), url(b.png);
}
```

is it possible to override only one part of the multiple values, i.e. (pseudocode):

```
h1.foo {
  background-image: default, default, url(c.png);
}
```

Comment: Is `background-image: url(a.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, black), url(b.png);` even valid css code?

Comment: CSS3 allows for multiple background declarations separated using the comma. I haven't used CSS3 much, though I'd venture a 'yes' to your question.

Comment: @elclanrs Yes it is, CSS3 allows for multiple background images (although validators may flag prefixed values).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently. You can do the following (change a single property's value in the background shorthand):

```
.foo {
    background: url('...') 50% 50% no-repeat,
                url('...') 50% 50% no-repeat,
                url('...') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.foo {
    background-position: 50% 50%, 75% 75%, 50% 50%;
}
```

But no matter how you tackle it, you will always have to declare each background image; you can't use 'inherit' for multiple background images as of yet.

Comment: actually there is an 'inherit' value, but I know what you mean.

Comment: Heh, I should have been more specific. I have clarified my answer.

Comment: I wonder what background-position would do to a -webkit-gradient()

Comment: It changes the starting point. Twitter actually use this technique in Bootstrap. They use subtle gradients on buttons, and they shift this gradient up (with a transition) when hovering.